# Adding a column of values in a tab delimited file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How can I add a column of values in a tab-separated file which has a certain number of rows? I have a input file like this:

```
SPATA17 1   217947738
LYPLAL1 1   219383905
FAM47E  4   77192838
SHROOM3 4   77660162
SHROOM3 4   77660731
SHROOM3 4   77662248
```

The desired looks like this:

```
SPATA17 1   217947738 file1
LYPLAL1 1   219383905 file1
FAM47E  4   77192838  file1
SHROOM3 4   77660162  file1
SHROOM3 4   77660731  file1
SHROOM3 4   77662248  file1
```

In this case, I want to add a column of values, up to the number of rows in the file. The value remains constant, such as `file1`.

The reason is I have 100 of those files. I don't want to open each file and paste a column.

Also is there any way to automate this, by going in a directory and adding a column of values?

The value comes from the filename, which has to be added in each row of the file in the last/first column.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a one-liner loop like this:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do sed -i "s/$/\t$f/" $f; done
```

For each file in the list, this will use `sed` to append to the end of each line a tab and the filename.

Explanation:

- Using the `-i` flag with `sed` to perform a replacement in-place, overwriting the file
- Perform a substitution with `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`. In this example PATTERN is `$`, the end of the line, and REPLACEMENT is `\t` (= a TAB), and `$f` is the filename, from the loop variable. The `s///` command is within double-quotes so that the shell can expand variables.

Comment: The code works.Can you explain the contents within quotes?

Comment: Just as "awk" is used while working with columns, is 'sed' also used for similar situations.I am newbie to 'awk' and 'sed'.

Comment: @Ron `sed` is most practical for pattern substitution and saving in-place. For your requirement of saving the file it was a relatively convenient option. If you don't need to write back to the same file you're processing, then `awk` is usually much easier to work with.

Comment: Personally, I get tripped up by `awk`'s input/output field separators too often, and so try to avoid using it whenever possible, making `sed` more appealing.

Answer (score 23):

Come on why you guys recommend those powerful tools when there's `paste` command!

```
$ cat a
A
B
C
D
$ cat b
1
2
3
4
$ paste a b
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
```

With a little trickery, you could use `paste` for the OP's purpose. However, it will not replace the files inplace:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do 
    paste $f <(yes $f | head -n $(cat $f | wc -l)) > $f.new
done
```

This will paste the respective filename as the last column of each file into new file `filename.new`

Comment: Thanks! `paste` is surely a hidden gem.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $0, FILENAME}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Comment: Since each file has different name,so I have to do this 100 times.Is there any way to do it once?

Comment: No, `FILENAME` is a variable in `awk`, it expand to current file name that `awk` is processing. You just do it one, feed all files to `awk`.

Comment: ok,but how to direct the output into a new file, of each file?does awk stores the each file while processing?

Comment: If you have `GNU awk 4.1.0` or later, you can use `-i` to edit inplace. Otherwise, you should redirect `awk` ouput to a temp file, then use `grep` to extract line from each files.

Comment: Well you can do `for file in *; do awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $0, FILENAME}' $file; done`