# How to insert a column between two other columns of output?

Tags: text-processing, columns

Please note that I'm aware of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117568/adding-a-column-of-values-in-a-tab-delimited-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095306/how-to-add-a-column-from-a-file-to-another-file) but they didn't help me.

I want to combine the outputs of two commands.

```
ls -1sh
```

And

```
wc -l
```

so I can do something like:

```
<combined command> o.img 1.img
  1512 412K 0.png
  1269 320K 1.png
  2781 732K total
```

Also there is a small problem with that ls does not include the sum of sizes.

Comment: `ls -1sh` may also print directory items

Comment: How come!? Can you give me an example?

Comment: just run `ls -1sh` on the folder which contains subfolders, you'll see. In your case you can not get `wc -l` from subfolder

Comment: I thought you meant the items inside directories:))

Comment: what useful information do you expect to get from running `wc -l` (which counts lines in a text file) on a .png image file?

Comment: @cas Nothing! that was just the file i had in hand:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` won't produce a total, but `du` can

```
du -sch *.csv
16K     LdevInfo.csv
8.0K    LunInfo.csv
4.0K    W.csv
4.0K    WwnInfo.csv
32K     total
```

`wc` will produce a total

```
 wc -l *.csv
  101 LdevInfo.csv
   66 LunInfo.csv
   62 W.csv
    8 WwnInfo.csv
  237 total
```

then simply `join`

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,2.1,2.2 v w
101 16K LdevInfo.csv
66 8.0K LunInfo.csv
62 4.0K W.csv
8 4.0K WwnInfo.csv
237 32K total
```

where

- `-j 2` tell join to use field 2 for matching
- `-o 1.1,2.1,2.2` print specified fileld FILENUM.FIELDNUM

or, you can use additionnal awk to pretty format

```
join -j 2  v w| awk '{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",$2,$3,$1}'
101     16K     LdevInfo.csv
66      8.0K    LunInfo.csv
62      4.0K    W.csv
8       4.0K    WwnInfo.csv
237     32K     total
```

PS: I don't have any `*.png` I use `*.csv` but this should work.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry! do you want me to send you some png!?

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to fix the ls issue that it doesn't include the total with the following function:

```
myls() {
    if [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
        ls -1sh "$@"
        ls -1s "$@" | cut -d' ' -f1 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=' total'
    else
        ls -1sh "$1"
    fi
}
```

You can put that in your `.bashrc` and load it.

After that you have to combine the outputs. There are multiple ways to do that. Here is one:
First you combine all the outputs with paste.
unfortunately paste only accepts files as arguments but you can use named pipes to take care of that:

```
combined() {
    paste <(wc -l "$@") <(myls "$@") | awk '{print $1, $3, $4}' | sort
}
```

You can put this function in your `.bashrc` now. I sorted them because I think that is mode readable. You can remove `| sort` if you don't want to sort them.

If you don't want to use an extra function you can do:

```
myd() {
    if [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
        tmp=`ls -1sh "$@";ls -1s "$@" | cut -d' ' -f1 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' | numfmt --to=iec --suffix=' total'`
    else
        tmp=`ls -1sh "$1"`
    fi
    paste <(wc -l "$@") <(echo "$tmp") | awk '{print $1, $3, $4}' | sort
}
```

Comment: This is working very well but it is giving me some other output to `[1] 1009
[2] 1010` before the output and `[1]-  Done                    myls "$@" > fA
[2]+  Done                    wc -l "$@" > fB` after.

Comment: You don't need named pipe for that, you can just do `paste <(myls "$0") <(wc -l "$0")` as well.

Comment: @WeijunZhou You are right. thanks. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Also I don't want to use an extra command. how can I do that without myls?