# Add two new columns in tab delimited file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have to add two new columns at the end of the tab-delimited file with specific entries. My file looks like this

```
chr2    88861474    88861574    IGKJ2
chr2    88861170    88861270    IGKJ3
chr2    88860835    88860935    IGKJ4
chr2    88860517    88860617    IGKJ5
```

Following is my expected output

```
chr2    88861474    88861574    IGKJ2   0   -
chr2    88861170    88861270    IGKJ3   0   -
chr2    88860835    88860935    IGKJ4   0   -
chr2    88860517    88860617    IGKJ5   0   -
```

I can make another file with `0` and `-` entries and using `paste` command i can merge the newly made file with my original file to get the desired output but I am looking for other options( using `awk` or `sed`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a Column of values in a tab delimited file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117568/adding-a-column-of-values-in-a-tab-delimited-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk it would look something like this:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $0, "0", "-"}' inputfile
```

`OFS` sets the output delimiter to `tab`, then just prints the desired fields after each line.

Answer (score 3):

If your `sed` support `\t` in the replacement part of its `s` command, you can try

```
sed 's/$/\t0\t-/' inputfile
```

If not and your shell supports the ksh93-style `$'...'` form of quotes:

```
sed $'s/$/\t0\t-/' inputfile
```

If not, you can always do:

```
TAB=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/\$/${TAB}0${TAB}-/" inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
   printf "%s\t0\t-\n" "${line}"
done < inputfile
```

Comment: While that would work with the sample input shown, it'd corrupt other input (e.g. containing backslashes or null values in the first or last fields or printf formatting chars like `%s`) and it would be extremely slow, orders of magnitude slower than a more robust sed or awk script that could handle any input.

Comment: Yes, see also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Use a Perl one-liner:**

```
perl -lpe '$_ = join "\t", $_, qw(0 -);' in_file > out_file
```

Or change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -lpe '$_ = join "\t", $_, qw(0 -);' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

**Method 2: Use `paste` and `yes`, *without* creating a temporary file:**

```
paste in_file <( yes 0$'\t'- | head -n $( cat in_file | wc -l) ) > out_file
```

This is a common method to add columns with constant values to a file. Unfortunately, it cannot change the file in-place. For that, you have to explicitly do this:

```
mv out_file in_file
```

**See also:**

- [`paste`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html)
- [`wc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html)
- [`yes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html)
- [Adding a Column of values in a tab delimited file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117568/13411)

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$(NF+1)="0\t-";print }' filename
```

output

```
chr2    88861474    88861574    IGKJ2   0   -
chr2    88861170    88861270    IGKJ3   0   -
chr2    88860835    88860935    IGKJ4   0   -
chr2    88860517    88860617    IGKJ5   0   -
```